# Why is there no grid-row in neat?

Tags: bourbon, neat

I want to tell Neat that I want to start a new row within the grid.
Unfortunately there is no grid-row in Neat.
Why is that and how do you tell Neat that you are finished with the current row?

Answer (score 4):

What you are looking for is likely `grid-container` → http://neat.bourbon.io/docs/latest/#grid-container

This mixin is a clearfix container that will cause a new 'row' to be created.

Answer (score 0):

I found out what I was looking for:

I placed a div around the content that should be in that new row.
Then I gave it a '@include grid-column;'
So the content appeared in a new row.